# Swiftui expanding menu expands whole HStack?

Tags: xcode, swiftui, menu

Is it possible to have an expanding menu that does not expand the HStack it is in?
I want a "menu bar" on top of my app and on the right is an expanding menu with all my objects in. But when I expand the menu all of the HStack expands which looks bad.
I tried putting a .fixedsize() on the HStack but it didn't help.
Do I have to move the menu or is it possible?

This is my code:

```
 HStack{
                Text("Input searchfunction here")
                    .foregroundColor(Color.white)
                    .padding()
                Spacer()
                Button(action: {
                    createViewIsActive = true
                    
                }, label: {
                    Text("Lägg till tecken.")
                        .foregroundColor(Color.white)
                        .onAppear {
                            
                            if signs.count != 0 {
                                
                                activeSign = signs[0]
                                
                                
                            }
                        }
                    Image(systemName: "plus")
                        .foregroundColor(Color.white)
                })
                    .padding()
                
                Button(action: {
                    deleteItems()
                }, label: {
                    Text("Delete")
                })
                
                Spacer()
                
                DisclosureGroup("Tecken", isExpanded: $isExpanded) {
                    ScrollView{
                        VStack{
                            ForEach(signs, id: \.self) { sign in
                                HStack{
                                    Text(sign.name!)
                                        .font(.title3)
                                        .padding(.all)
                                        .onTapGesture {
                                            self.isExpanded.toggle()
                                            self.activeSign = sign
                                        }
                                }
                                
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
                .accentColor(.white) // Arrow color
                .font(.title3)
                .foregroundColor(.white) // Text color
                .padding(.all)
                .cornerRadius(8)
                .frame(minWidth: 10, maxWidth: 300)
                
                
            }
            .background(Color.gray)
            .padding()
```

Comment: `DisclosureGroup` is not a menu it is just another view within same your `HStack`, so expanding it affects all layout within this container. You need to consider either `ZStack` or `overlay`.

Comment: Thank you, I will try ZStack!